# CSS for disappearing div animation is not pausing on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on a snackbar that appears/disappears after `x` amount of time, and I would like the timer to be paused when I hover over the snackbar.

However, it seems that the way I have laid this out doesn't allow this to work, with the `setTimeout` and the `useState`...

I can't find much online about how this can be fixed that I can work out, so any help would be appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dyq9mg

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {

  const [showSnack, setShowSnack] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setShowSnack(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSnack(false);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      <Snack show={showSnack} />
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Snack.js**

```
const Snack = ({show}) => {

  return(
    <div className={`my-snack ${show ? 'show' : ''}`}>My Snackbar</div>
  );
}
```

**index.css**

```
.my-snack {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: lightgray;
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-snack.show {
  visibility: visible;
  animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 9.6s;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

.my-snack:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused paused;
}

/*Animations to fade the snackbar in and out*/
@keyframes fadein {
  from {bottom: -500px;}
  to {bottom: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {bottom: 0;}
  to {bottom: -500px; opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: `animation-play-state: paused paused;` – you just need one `paused` and the fade in/out animation will pause on hover. If the goal is to stop the snackbar from _hiding_ on hover, that will still not work as you are always unconditionally hiding the snackbar with `toggle`.

Comment: One way you could solve this is by using the `onAnimationEnd` event instead of a timer. I'd recommend this approach over a timer since you'd control all the timing through the css and the component reacts to when the animation has finished. One note about this specific approach (for your use case) is you have to know the animation name in the js since you're using multiple animations at once. e.g. `(e.animationName === 'fadeout')` https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szkq7w

Comment: @DennisMartinez - If you add this as an answer below, I will happily accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could solve this is by using the [onAnimationEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event instead of a timer. I'd recommend this approach over a timer since you'd control all the timing through css and the component would react to when the animation has finished.

```
<Snack
  show={showSnack}
  onAnimationEnd={(e) => {
    setShowSnack(false)
  }}
/>

const Snack = ({ show, onAnimationEnd }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`my-snack ${show ? 'show' : ''}`}
      onAnimationEnd={(e) => {
        if (e.animationName === 'fadeout') {
          onAnimationEnd(e)
        }
      }}>
      My Snackbar
    </div>
  )
}
```

One note about this specific approach (for your use case) is you have to know the animation name in the js since you're using multiple animations at once. e.g. `(e.animationName === 'fadeout')`

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-szkq7w

Comment: Thanks for posting as an answer @Dennis - Would it be possible to add a button to the snackbar to dismiss it early?

Comment: @physicsboy sure you could do that. It's out of scope for this question so I recommend asking a new one for that particular case. I did update the example to show one way to do that but I still recommend a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be conflating the CSS animation to fade in the snackbar with the showing and hiding of the snackbar itself. You could use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` to pause and start the timer respectively. Of course, you'd have to pass these to the `Snack` component and set them on the DOM node.

```js
  const timer = useRef(null);

  const clearSnackTimer = () => clearTimeout(timer.current);

  const startSnackTimer = () => timer.current = setTimeout(() => setShowSnack(false), 1000);

  const toggle = () => {
    setShowSnack(!showSnack);
    startSnackTimer();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
      <Snack show={showSnack} onMouseOver={clearSnackTimer} onMouseOut={startSnackTimer} />
    </div>
  );
```

Something is still wonky with the `fadeout` transition, but I think this solves for the requirement to pause hiding the snackbar hiding on hover, if that is your intention.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go with the advice first written by @DennisMartinez in the comments of the original question, around using `onAnimationEnd` rather than a `setTimeout` solution.